# Cordova FirefoxOS build folder is not recognized when I attempt to build

Tags: windows, mobile, cordova, cmd, firefox-os

**OS/Environment:** Windows 7 Ultimate x64; cordova cli version 3.3.1-0.1.2

**Problem:** Upon running `cordova build` in the command shell I receive the following error:

`Error: An error occurred while building the firefoxos          project.'Z:\MobileDev\hello\platforms\firefoxos\cordova\build'
 is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`
(For the detailed error see here: http://pastebin.com/bL9QpB2v)

I used the windows explorer to look at the directory `Z:\MobileDev\hello\platforms\firefoxos\cordova\build` , and I noticed something strange. The folder icon was a blank white icon, rather than the usual folder icon. Also, I could not change directories into it using the command console.
[image]

**Question:** What is causing this error and how do I fix it so that I can successfully run 'cordova build' for the firefoxos?

Comment: probably not too helpful because I don’t use windows, but `build` is probably for Linux/Mac systems. Try running the `build.bat` maybe? `build` is a script not a folder, it is just that windows too dumb to understand what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I just now realized that my original photo was of amazon fire os (not firefoxos). So in reality there is nothing named `build`. If this is a problem specific to the windows environment, I may choose to use a linux VM.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox OS apps are built using web technologies that do not require building/compiling. You can safely ignore this error.

That said, ignorable errors are sure annoying and Cordova for Firefox OS will soon have build scripts to help package your app, [it's under development](https://github.com/apache/cordova-firefoxos/pull/7).

Just make sure to run `cordova prepare` to propagate your changes to the `platforms/firefoxos` folder.